# How to Disable Single Monaco Editor Syntax Rule

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

I have a use case where I have a monaco editor that allows users to write a custom function. This function must be in the format

```
function (source, callback) {
    callback(source);
}
```

because we then assign the output to a variable which we use to run data through.

However I'm getting the "Identifier Expected" error. Is there a way to disable this single syntax rule?

[image: The error]

Comment: After some user has answered your question it is not allowed to change dramatically your question because of the answers could downwoted because they would look like wrong answers. In this case you have to use the comments (below each answer) or to ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, a proper API has been introduced to ignore certain errors. This should fix the above false-positive:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    diagnosticCodesToIgnore: [1003]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

But it is not a Monaco Editor Syntax Rule!

It is the JavaScript error! And you get this error because if you write it like this:

```
function (source, callback)
{
    callback(source);
}
```

then you will can not to use this function!

You have to write it with name like this:

```
function funcName(source, callback)
{
    callback(source);
}
```

Only, if you have this function as a parameter like here:

```
anotherFunction(function(source, callback)
{
    callback(source);
});
```

you can write it without a name. Or if you use it immediately like follows:

```
(function(source, callback)
{
    callback(source);
})('Hello, world!', alert);
```

Comment: Exactly, which is what we do. This function becomes a variable for another function. So I understand why it shows me this error, but because of the way that I'm using this function, the error is irrelevant. I'm looking to hide it from the users view. Maybe I should clarify the question.

Comment: We take the value of the editor editor.getValue() and wrap it (as you have in anotherFunction example) then create a blob out of it to execute it.

Comment: @GeorgeKemp, but in this case you could or may be better – you have to write a name (because of an error) and can take the value of the editor with editor.getValue()  and you can use it **with** name **too**.

Comment: @GeorgeKemp, you can use it **with** name **too** like follows: `anotherFunction(function someName(source, callback){callback(source);});`

Comment: I appreciate your correction to my syntax, however, the solution that I'm looking for is the ability to disable the error highlighting for that particular error within Monaco. I appreciate your help with possible workarounds, but unfortunately, that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: There is however a worker within the language features in Monaco that interprets these rules and applies error dialogs and highlighting. That's what I'm attempting to disable.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation where I want to allow a return statement at the global level, because my script is a 'function'. 
Typescript flags the return as an error with 'A 'return' statement can only be used within a function body.'

A solution I found is to filter the model markers. This is god awful because of the string matching, but it works. There is a slight flicker in the UI as the decoration appears and then immediately disappears.

After you create the editor, subscribe to decoration changes:

```
   this.editor.onDidChangeModelDecorations( e => this.onDidChangeModelDecorations(e) )
```

Where you go and get the current markers, filter them, and put them back in the editor:

```
onDidChangeModelDecorations(e: monaco.editor.IModelDecorationsChangedEvent)
{
    let model = this.editor.getModel()
    let markers = monaco.editor.getModelMarkers( { owner:'typescript', resource: model.uri} )

    // We have to filter out the error that the editor gives on global returns.
    // Unfortunately the error code is null in the marker, so we have option but to 
    // match on the text of the error.
    // It will be obvious if this regresses.
    let filtered = markers.filter( marker => marker.message != "A 'return' statement can only be used within a function body." )
    if (filtered.length != markers.length)
    {
        monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(model, 'typescript', filtered)
    }
}
```

Hopefully we can at least get error codes to match on in the future.
There might be more info in the marker that you could better filter on, have a look at the marker object in a debugger.